# c++: How to declare std::functions without creating member functions to assign to them

Tags: c++, function, callback

I'm trying to write a "conditions" class to check if a given condition returns true or false, in an rpg game.

**Conditions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Conditions
{
public:
    bool check(int i);
    void initialize();

private:
    std::vector<std::function<bool()>> functions;
};
```

**Conditions.cpp**

```
    bool Conditions::check(int i)
{
    if (i >= functions.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Conditions::functions's size is " << functions.size() << " but you've tried to enter: " << i << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return functions[i]();
    }
}

void Conditions::initialize()
{
    //Here I want to initialize all the conditions manually and push them 
    //into functions member variable.
}
```

the question is , how can I create this functions without creating new member functions for each of them(there will be most likely more than 200 functions)

is it possible to write something like:

```
functions.push_back( 
  { 
    if(GameInfo::player.gold>200) return true; 
    else return false; 
  } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
functions.push_back([this]
{ 
    if (GameInfo::player.gold > 200) return true; 
    else return false; 
});
```

If you don't actually need to access any members of `Conditions` in the function, then you can also remove the `this` capture entirely:

```
functions.push_back([]
{ 
    if (GameInfo::player.gold > 200) return true; 
    else return false; 
});
```

---

By the way, your specific function example can be extremely simplified like this:

```
functions.push_back([]
{ 
    return GameInfo::player.gold > 200;
});
```

Comment: yeah, edited version of your answer fits much better to my use. I decided to change everything inside conditions class into static,  so [this] was giving me errors since it cannot be used with static. Thanks alot.